# How to connect to Google BigQuery from abinito

Tags: google-bigquery, ab-initio

I would like to read the data connecting to google big query from AbInitio GDE to copy the data. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to contact support or `forum.abinitio.com`